# Open dialog from server side

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Basically on the client side i have this jquery function

```
function OpenDialog()
{
$('.jqmWindow').jqm();


   $('#ConfirmEnquiry').jqmShow();



}
```

I want to call this function when an imageButton is clicked, but i want to call it from server side, from a Vb file.

Vb code

```
 Protected Sub btnimg_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnimg.Click
 'opendialog here
```

any help would be aprreciated

Answer (score 0):

You mixed up a few things.

You can't call a dialog on the server. Dialog appears in the browser, your server doesn't know what a browser is. So, no, you can't do it.

Do your validation on the server and if it passes print into HTML a line of javascript to call the dialog. You could pack it into a control, but still, the dialog is invoked from the client with javascript, not server.

Sadly this is a common mistake with people that learned to do web Microsoft style. .NET hides a lot of normal web stuff and adds a layer of abstraction over it. A lot of stuff you see in your server code isn't really executed on the server. It just generates javascipt which does it on the client. I'm guessing you want something similar with your dialog. Lear how the web really operates, not just how to hack something in .NET